# EF doesn't like a 1:many cascade delete

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am getting the error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Signups_Events_EventId' on table 'Signups' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

This makes no sense to me as this is a clean 1:many relationship.

```
public class Signup
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public required AppUser Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Signup>? Signups { get; set; }
}

public class AppUser : IAuditTrail, IPrimaryEntities
{
    public ICollection<Event>? Events { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Signup>? Signups { get; set; }
}
```

How/why is it unhappy with the `Event : Signup` relationship? This appears to me to be a very simple 1:many relationship where a delete of an `Event` should cascade and delete the signups.

Is there something I need to do to then remove those signups from `AppUser.Signups`? Shouldn't those be cascade deleted too?

---

**Update:** if I add the following, then it can create the database.

```
public class EventConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Event>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Event> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Address);

        // In the program we need to make sure a user is not an Event.Owner anywhere before deleting them.
        // This lets EF know to not worry about cascading deletes for AppUser.Events.
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Owner)
            .WithMany(u => u.Events)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

I believe this says that when deleting the `Event.Owner` `AppUser`, then take `NoAction` on the events in it's `AppUser.Events` collection.

If so, this presents two questions:

1. First, how does it know the 1:many is `AppUser.Events : Event.Owner`? That seems to work but how does it know to use the property `Owner`? Is it based on the type of the property? And if so, what would happen if I had two properties of that type (I don't)?
2. On the delete of an `AppUser`, this leaves all the `Event` records where its `Event.Owner` (`OwnerId` actually) with an invalid FK. Will a delete of the `AppUser` record fail in this case because of this FK requirement? Should I overload my `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` and in that, walk children when an `AppUser` is deleted and delete the child events?

---

Full error message:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Signups] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserId] int NOT NULL,
    [EventId] int NOT NULL,
    [RoiRating] int NOT NULL,
    [EnjoyRating] int NOT NULL,
    [VolunteerRating] int NOT NULL,
    [Summarization] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Closed] bit NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] bit NOT NULL,
    [Created] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] rowversion NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Signups] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_AppUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AppUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_Events_EventId] FOREIGN KEY ([EventId]) REFERENCES [Events] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
{
  "Timestamp": "21:14:22 ",
  "EventId": 20102,
  "LogLevel": "Error",
  "Category": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command",
  "Message": "Failed executing DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType=\u0027Text\u0027, CommandTimeout=\u002730\u0027]\r\nCREATE TABLE [Signups] (\r\n    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,\r\n    [UserId] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [EventId] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [RoiRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [EnjoyRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [VolunteerRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [Summarization] nvarchar(max) NULL,\r\n    [Closed] bit NOT NULL,\r\n    [Deleted] bit NOT NULL,\r\n    [Created] datetime2 NOT NULL,\r\n    [RowVersion] rowversion NOT NULL,\r\n    CONSTRAINT [PK_Signups] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),\r\n    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_AppUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AppUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,\r\n    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_Events_EventId] FOREIGN KEY ([EventId]) REFERENCES [Events] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE\r\n);",
  "State": {
    "Message": "Failed executing DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType=\u0027Text\u0027, CommandTimeout=\u002730\u0027]\r\nCREATE TABLE [Signups] (\r\n    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,\r\n    [UserId] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [EventId] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [RoiRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [EnjoyRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [VolunteerRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [Summarization] nvarchar(max) NULL,\r\n    [Closed] bit NOT NULL,\r\n    [Deleted] bit NOT NULL,\r\n    [Created] datetime2 NOT NULL,\r\n    [RowVersion] rowversion NOT NULL,\r\n    CONSTRAINT [PK_Signups] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),\r\n    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_AppUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AppUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,\r\n    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_Events_EventId] FOREIGN KEY ([EventId]) REFERENCES [Events] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE\r\n);",
    "elapsed": "12",
    "parameters": "",
    "commandType": "Text",
    "commandTimeout": 30,
    "newLine": "\r\n",
    "commandText": "CREATE TABLE [Signups] (\r\n    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,\r\n    [UserId] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [EventId] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [RoiRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [EnjoyRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [VolunteerRating] int NOT NULL,\r\n    [Summarization] nvarchar(max) NULL,\r\n    [Closed] bit NOT NULL,\r\n    [Deleted] bit NOT NULL,\r\n    [Created] datetime2 NOT NULL,\r\n    [RowVersion] rowversion NOT NULL,\r\n    CONSTRAINT [PK_Signups] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),\r\n    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_AppUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [AppUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,\r\n    CONSTRAINT [FK_Signups_Events_EventId] FOREIGN KEY ([EventId]) REFERENCES [Events] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE\r\n);",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "Failed executing DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType=\u0027{commandType}\u0027, CommandTimeout=\u0027{commandTimeout}\u0027]{newLine}{commandText}"
  },
  "Scopes": []
}
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Signups_Events_EventId' on table 'Signups' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:e4518a03-b5e4-4bb1-b69b-29cab3418f83
Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Signups_Events_EventId' on table 'Signups' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Comment: at a first glance i see many cicles Singup<->Event->AppUser(to both Signup and Event). Also i envision that there is a chance to get orphans in the DB

Comment: @jmvcollaborator as Signup is the many in the 1:many from AppUser and Event, how does that create a cycle? Isn't it set up that deleting a record in the many part has no impact on the 1 part?

Comment: in that case the 1 part should allow null values, does it make sense ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I don't think that makes sense. The Event has many Signups. If the Event is deleted, by definition all the Signups should be deleted. A Signup makes no sense if Signup.Event or Signup.User is null. The Signup's whole purpose is to say User X has signed up for Event Y. ???